# CSS stretch or fit background image

Tags: html, css

I wanted to stretch or fit my background image using css so it is always in 100% of width and height no matter what the screen size is. This is asked many times and everyone suggests to use background-size:100% and it will work. but using background-size only fits my image's width and the height is still cropped.
I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this.
Thans very much

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You tried `background-size: 100%`,
CSS interprets this as `100% width, automatic height` which will look like this:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

What you want is the second argument (height) to be 100% too, so you should do this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

**END EDIT**

Try:

```
background-size: cover;
```

This will fit the width or height and overflow the rest

Or:

```
background-size: contain;
```

This will make the image as large as possible without changing it's aspect ratio.

You can read more about the css3 background-size property [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: I have tried cover but the problem is it fits the width and the height is still cropped, I don't want to keep the aspect ratio and I want both width and height to be fit no matter what the screen size is. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer a little bit, but if cover is not what you want, background-size: 100% 100%; should do what you want? what are the problems you're having with that?

Comment: Thanks setting background-size:100% 100% did the trick I was using only background-size:100% . Thanks very much if you could edit the answer to contain this would be great. Thanks again

Comment: I was doing that haha ;) glad it helped you ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
background: url('Your image URL') 100%;
```

or

```
background: url('Your image URL') 100% no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this CSS rule:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: center center
background-size: cover; // this makes img full-screen (full-width & full-height)
```